# ByteArray.clear() not working for shared ByteArrays?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, air, worker

It appears that `ByteArray.clear()` doesn't do anything when I share a `ByteArray` with a worker. Take this code as an example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.system.WorkerDomain;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _worker:Worker;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (Worker.current.isPrimordial)
            {
                initMain();
            }
            else
            {
                initWorker();
            }
        }

        private function initMain():void 
        {
            _worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(loaderInfo.bytes, true);

            var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            bytes.writeUnsignedInt(12836439);
            bytes.shareable = true;
            _worker.setSharedProperty("bytes", bytes);
            bytes.clear();
            trace(bytes.length);
        }

        private function initWorker():void
        {
            //worker stuff would go here
        }

    }

}
```

This traces `4`, while it should be `0`. If I comment out either `bytes.shareable = true;` or `_worker.setSharedProperty("bytes", bytes);`, it works perfectly, but the combination seems to somehow disable the `clear()` method.

Curiously enough, however, this only happens when compiling for AIR. When compiling for Flash Player, clearing works just as it should and this code traces `0`.

Anybody know what's up?

Comment: Have you tried setting `length` to 0 instead of calling `clear()`? Same effect, though it takes a different route to get there. Maybe it will have a different result. Beyond that possibility, this is an interesting issue. Might be a bug worth reporting to Adobe.

Comment: Setting `length` to 0 is indeed what I'm using to work around the issue. For my purposes the effect is essentially the same, but not being able to free up memory (which `clear()` does) could be a problem in the future. I might report it to Adobe, since this is really odd.

Comment: I am still experiencing even on AIR 28. It looks like it is not fixed yet :(

Comment: @CaslavSabani I doubt it will ever get fixed at this rate. I've since switched to using Haxe for any application I used AIR for. I would recommend checking it out, as it's very similar to AS3.